# How to resolve this warning: The numeric literal appears to be unnecessary

Tags: java, static-analysis

MY Java code has section as follows:

```
private static final double EPSILON = 0.0000001;
private boolean equals(double a, double b) {
    return (Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON);
}
```

But when I compile it I get the following warning:

```
[WARN] The numeric literal '0.0000001' appears to be unnecessary. [NumericLiteral]
```

I don't know how I can fix this error.

Comment: What IDE and Java version are you using?

Comment: Compiles fine for me, even with `-Xlint:all`. Are you sure you've posted the correct / relevant / full code?

Comment: I use eclipse at my machine, which doesn't give any warning. But this is part of a coursera assignment that I am submitting and their grader checks this and gives this warning. I think they use static analysis on top of compilation.